# Migration from nexus to artifactory

Tags: nexus, artifactory

I have a task of migrating all the repositories from nexus to artifactory. I user nexus2artifactory tool (https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory)  for that which didn't work. It was throwing an error like Migration error: Unable to GET api/security/groups: 400 in nexus2artifactory and Migration error: Unable to GET api/security/users: 400 in nexus2artifactory. If someone has already worked on it. Let me know the steps you followed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to migrate to Artifactory OSS? It looks like the users/groups/permissions APIs nexus2artifactory uses are only available in Pro: https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory/issues/20

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why I'm unable to see any default maven projects in the artifactory open source installation, I'm not able generate the settings as well. It says "No repositories match the selected tool"

Comment: In order to migrate only repositories (most of them are maven) at-least from nexus to artifactory OSS, Kindly let me know the steps to follow.

Comment: In the migrator, you can go into the users, groups, and permissions menus and deselect all of them. The tool won't try to migrate them, and your repositories should migrate without issue.

Comment: @DarthFennec Can you please suggest me on this.. https://ibb.co/gdcCPH I don't see any default maven repositories here

Comment: Artifactory doesn't come with default Maven repositories. You'll have to make them. Once you do that, you should be able to generate the settings.